# Outlook 2010 end users + Exchange online server allows Graph API usage?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect an application I've written with an old on-premise Exchange 2010 server. Obviously this is not supported, I was wondering if Outlook 2010 end users + Exchange online server would allow the use of Microsoft Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

If the Mailbox is an Office365 Mailbox (or you've configured hybrid https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deva/2019/03/16/deep-dive-how-to-configure-exchange-on-premise-server-hybrid-integration-with-office-365-test-rest-api-calls/) then you can use the Graph API to access that Mailbox. The version of Outlook doesn't really matter as the API is strictly service side, but depending on what your actually doing client side you may find a lot client side integration pain and you would be better to upgrade the latest version of Outlook on the clients. That would give you more options when you redevelop your application as you can make use of the new Addin's platform etc.